# Java i.o FilterInputStream

Tags: java, java-io

Can FilterInputStream class be classed as an instantiated class or not?

I am struggling to understand this, this is not an abstract class but it has a protected constructor which means only subclasses can instantiate this.

Now do I say FilterInputStream class can be instantiated or not? 
Because If I try something like this:

```
FilterInputStream fis = new FilterInputStream(null);
```

It will complain, but of course if say

```
FilterInputStream fis = new DataInputStream(null);
```

than this works fine.

Sorry for such a novice question, I tend to think this probably has nothing to do with java i.o. but its a question of more to do with access control and possibly wider OOP concepts.

Anyway i'd be happy to get an opinion on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Can FilterInputStream class be classed as an instantiated class or not?

Yes, it can.  It can be *directly* instantiated, in two ways:

- Since the constructor is `protected`, it is accessible to other classes in the `java.io` package, whether or not they are subclasses of `FilterInputStream`.  Any class in the `java.io` package should therefore be able to create `FilterInputStream` instances<sup>1</sup>.
- You should be able to use reflection to find the `protected` constructor, override its access, and invoke it to create a `FilterInputStream` instance.

Both of these would create an object that is an instance of `FilterInputStream` and not any subtypes.

By contrast:

- If `FilterInputStream` was declared as `abstract`, the first approach would give a compilation error, and the second one would result in an exception.
- In your second example, the true type of the object being created is `DataInputStream`.  This "is-a" `FilterInputStream` and `instanceof` will say that too.  But calling `getClass()` on it will tell you what its true type is.  (The `DataInputStream` will only behave like a `FilterInputStream` to the extent that it does not override behaviour in ways that do not conform to the API contract.)

---

<sup>1 - There is a practical issue here though.  The `java.io` package is effectively "closed" by convention, and by JVM security.  This means that an "ordinary" application cannot add classes to the `java.io` package.  This effectively closes off this approach ... unless you are prepared to "tinker" with the JVM.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The second example instantiates a derived class, not FilterInputStream itself, and then stores the result in a reference of type FilterInputStream. The two examples are not equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

FilterInputStream does not have a public constructor (it is protected - [see the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html)), so you can't instantiate it directly. DataInputStream is derived from FilterInputStream (and DataInputStream does have a public constructor), so it can be instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

Using the logic found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html), while you cannot (outside of a subclass) instantiate `FilterInputStream`, you can still (as you do in your second example) acquire an [instance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) of `FilterInputStream`.

It is more semantics than anything else.

EDIT: According to the terminology "Instantiating a Class" explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html), in your second example you are, in fact, instantiating `FilterInputStream`, since `DataInputStream` is a subclass of `FilterInputStream`, and therefore considered a `FilterInputStream`.

Comment: It is nothing but semantics, but semantics aren't mere trivia.

Comment: In this instance the fact it is only a semantic issue just confuses the situation.

Comment: I don't know what '*only* a semantic issue' means, and I don't see why that would confuse anybody. Programming languages are full of 'semantic issues'. This is one of them.

Comment: Human language is different from computer language. What we call this situation has absolutely no impact on what is happening. We can argue about whether or not you are "instantiating `FilterInputStrea`", but that doesn't change what the code is actually doing. That's the nice thing about code- it doesn't care what we call various processes or how we name things. Only what we are doing matters, not what we say we are doing.

Comment: Semantics is not about 'what we call' things: it's about their *meaning.* The semantics I am talking about are the semantics rules of the Java Programming Language, which are being enforced by the compiler.